# How can I create a wifi hotspot which passes all traffics to local proxy server?

Tags: tethering, proxy, http

I have a mitmproxy server listening on port 9999 and my macbook pro is connected to internet with usb tethering.

I want to make a wifi hotspot which forwards all request to the mitmproxy server. How can I do this?

I want network communication like this:
Client connected to hotspot <-> Hotspot (mac) <-> local proxy server <-> tethering (usb) <-> phone <-> internet

**Context**:

I'm insisting that all sites must use https. So I have to demonstrate a security issue cause by using http. (They calls the script injection problem 'theoretical')